# Yii, how to have controller code that runs in all views

Tags: php, yii

I was wondering if there is an ideal way of having the same code running in every single view file.

Instead of having to modify all controllers and all actions and add snippets of code, is there a way to have a controller and action that is always called by any view (not partial views)?

What I need in all views is code that gets the current logged in user and gets the data that is in other related tables.

The following is one of the action methods for one of the views

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    // the following line should be included for every single view
    $user_profile = YumUser::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id)->profile;

    $this->layout = 'column2';
    $this->render('index', array('user_profile' => $user_profile));

}
```

Comment: If you need to repeat controller logic it shouldn't be there in the first place. You can create a service class to handle the shared logic.

Comment: Ok @Bart thanks for that, any advice in setting up a service class to handle shared logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using a Layout and a Base Controller.

If you come from the Yii code generator, there should be a `Controller` class in `components` folder.

If your controller `ExampleController extends Controller` instead of `CController`,

In `Controller` you can assign:

```
public function getUserProfile() {
  return YumUser::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id)->profile;
}
```

And in your layout file:

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($this->getUserProfile()); ?>
```

Because `$this` refers to the controller, and the controller inherits the property called `$user_profile`.

However, you should assign `profile` and other things that won't vary with `setState` on login to the session. That way you can do something like:

```
 <p class="nav navbar-text">Welcome, <i><?php echo Yii::app()->User->name; ?></i></p>
```

Example for setting a state in MySQLUserIdentity (done by me).

```
class MySqlUserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{

  private $_id;

  public function authenticate()
  {
    $user = User::model()->findByAttributes( array( 'username' => $this->username ) );
    if( $user === null )
      $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if( $user->password !== md5( $this->password ) )
      $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
      $this->_id = $user->id;
      $this->setState( 'username', $user->username );
      $this->setState( 'name', $user->name );
      $this->setState( 'surname', $user->surname );
      $this->setState( 'email', $user->email );
      $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
  }

  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->_id;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the component controller, that's nice!
However @Jorge entering that code in the controller returns a parse error as it seems to accept only strings and arrays in he variables

Comment: It is not a component, it is in components folder lol. You could create a folder called base_controllers and set it to be autoloaded in config/main.php

Comment: I updated my answer, forgot that object's properties must be constant at the moment of object instantation, moved it to a function.

Answer (score 3):

As posted in comment it is not good to put repeated logic in controller. Remember MVC logic - **thick model**, wise view and *thin controlller*. For displaying logged in user data i recommend creating a widget. Than you can place that widget in your layout, or in any view.

Most simple one is

```
class MyWidget extends CWidget
{
    private $userData = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->userData = YumUser::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id)->profile;
        // Do any init things here
    }

    public function run()
    {
        return $this->render('viewName', array('user_profile' => $userData));
    }
}
```

Then in any view (or layout which in fact is view too) you can use it:

```
$this->widget('path.to.widget.MyWidget');
```

For more info see [docs on Yii widgets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget)